# Colouring only vertices with big degrees

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $k$ be the chromatic number of graph $G$. Is it enough to colour only maximum subgraph $F$ with minimum degree at least $k$ and then colour rest of the vertices with greedy algorithm?

I need to show that if I know how to colour $F$, then I can colour the whole graph. I know that we can colour rest of vertices with degree smaller than $k$ with greedy algorithm but what with vertices with degree $\ge k$ outside $F$?

I guess we can prove it using the fact that this $F$ is *maximum* subgraph but I really cannot see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the greedy algorithm can be used and about the importance of the fact that $F$ is of maximum size.

The key thing to remember about the greedy algorithm is that it depends on an ordering of the vertices—you color each vertex with the smallest color not already applied to one of its neighbors.

So, let’s say you’ve colored $F$. Now, if $F$ is not the whole graph, their must be some vertex $v\in G\setminus F$ with degree less than $k$ (if this isn't obvious consider it an exercise to the reader). If we color $v$ *last* in our greedy process, it will always be possible to color it with a color from $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$. So that’s what we will do: our ordering of the vertices not in $F$, which we are coloring greedily, will have $v$ last.

Now, try doing the same thing with the graph $G\setminus \{v\}$, and you should see a road toward the complete solution.

Comment: Ohh now I see it, you're correct :) Thank you so much for your help!